# Wordpress blog is zoomed in

Tags: wordpress

I am attaching blog to my static website www.quickwebcard.com 
I am new to Wordpress, so I can't figure out this issue. If you look at my blog on Ipad  - www.quickwebcard.com/blog it is zoomed in compared to home page. Everything is bigger, including fonts and logo. Can anybody help me?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Viewport.

On your home page it is correct:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

On your blog it is incorrect:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```